# When does an object get disposed if it holds no reference?

Tags: c#, sqldataadapter

If the method GetResults() is called repeatedly, is it possible to have multiple instances or does it dispose of itself at the end of its scope?

```
public static DataTable GetResults()
{
    DataTable dataTable;
    new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, new SqlConnection(connString)).Fill(dataTable);
    return dataTable;
}
```

Comment: The Garbage Collector will call the finalizer, which you can make call `Dispose()` yourself. Since there are no references to your adapter, it will be collected the next time garbage is picked up.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel The GC *might* call the finalizer, not *will* call the finalizer.  If deterministic cleanup is important, you need to be explicitly disposing of the resource.

Comment: @Servy: right, pretty important distinction.

Answer (score 2):

Disposing of objects is about disposing of *objects*. It has nothing to do with whether or not the object is stored in a variable.

Answer (score -2):

When using the Dispose strategy, its just for cleaning up. Even when disposing the object may still be "alive". Its only the GC that chooses to deleting objects.

So when using Sql connections, its a good idea to using the Dispose strategy to close the connection.